# Visualization of comparison between 3 groups (Bargraph vs line graph)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using R markdown and have the following dataset extracted by dput

```
structure(list(BMI_CLASS = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_), levels = c("Healthy Weight", "Overweight", "Obesity"
), class = "factor"), KOOS_SYMP_PRE = c(53.1, 49.5, 43), KOOS_SYMP_2Y = c(65.6, 
64.9, 62.4), KOOS_SYMP_5Y = c(66.3, 65.7, 57.4), KOOS_PAIN_PRE = c(55, 
52.4, 43.2), KOOS_PAIN_2Y = c(74.3, 73.2, 69.5), KOOS_PAIN_5Y = c(70.5, 
70.6, 61.4), KOOS_ADL_PRE = c(65.1, 60.8, 51.3), KOOS_ADL_2Y = c(82, 
78.8, 73.4), KOOS_ADL_5Y = c(78.8, 78.5, 66.9), KOOS_SPORT_PRE = c(30.4, 
27, 21.8), KOOS_SPORT_2Y = c(51.4, 49.1, 46.4), KOOS_SPORT_5Y = c(51.8, 
44.8, 37.9), KOOS_QOL_PRE = c(29.8, 28.2, 25), KOOS_QOL_2Y = c(55.4, 
52.1, 50.5), KOOS_QOL_5Y = c(52.1, 51.8, 43.3), KOOS_TOTAL_PRE = c(52.5, 
49.1, 42.1), KOOS_TOTAL_2Y = c(70.8, 71, 66), KOOS_TOTAL_5Y = c(69.5, 
69.1, 59.2)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I am trying to visualize the difference in the scores between the 3 groups ( healthy weight, overweight and obesity) over time.
I used the following codes, but I get an error message (Error: Must request at least one colour from a hue palette.
Is there something wrong in the code? Or is there a better way to visualize with bargraph or line graph the comparison between the 3 groups over time?

## Ordering the data

```
PROMS_KOOS_BMI$BMI_CLASS <- factor(PROMS_KOOS_BMI$BMI_CLASS,
                         levels = c("Healthy Weight","Overweight","Obesity"))
```

## Melt the data frame to long format

```
PROMS_KOOS_BMI_long <- melt(PROMS_KOOS_BMI, id.vars = "BMI_CLASS", variable.name = "TIME", value.name = "SCORE")
```

### Create a bar plot for the average scores across groups

```
ggplot(PROMS_KOOS_BMI_long, aes(x = TIME, y = SCORE, fill = BMI_CLASS)) +
  ggplot2::geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  labs(title = "Comparison of KOOS Scores Between Groups Over Time",
       x = "KOOS SCORE TIME", y = "KOOS SCORE") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: In the provided data sample, BMI_CLASS is NA for each point. If I rerun after setting, say, `PROMS_KOOS_BMI$BMI_CLASS <- factor("Healthy Weight")` it runs fine.

Comment: BMI_ClASS is a column contain 3 characters and imported it as text ( Healthy Weight, Overweight, Obesity). I tried multiple times still giving the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like your input step might be the problem if it comes in as NA everywhere. How are you importing it? Is it NA at that point or in a subsequent step?

Comment: I import it with the following code:

Comment: library(readxl)
PROMS_KOOS_BMI <- read_excel("E:/MY PROJECTS/HHFT HTO AND BMI/PROMS_KOOS_BMI.xlsx", 
    col_types = c("text", "numeric", "numeric", 
        "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
        "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
        "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
        "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
        "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
        "numeric"))
View(PROMS_KOOS_BMI)